# Ionic angular radio default checked

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, radio-group

I have a radio list group and i am looking for solution to check by default the radio with value="free_shipping:0" in the group, which is second in the group.

```html
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="chosen_shipping" 
(ngModelChange)="updateShipping(chosen_shipping)" 
class="ship">

          <ion-item *ngFor="let method of shipping | keys" >
            <ion-label>{{method.value.method_title}}
            </ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="{{method.value.id + ':' + method.value.instance_id}}" >
            </ion-radio>
          </ion-item>

   </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set default value from your component

```
chosen_shipping = "free_shipping:0"
```

This will set the default selected radio for your ionic radio.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `handleCartInit(results) {
        this.cart = results;
        this.shipping = results.zone_shipping;
        this.chosen_shipping = "free_shipping:0";
    }`